# Rails 4 query database from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.2.4
on cloud9.

I have a model named 'car'
I want to retrieve car data in next field of form by using carname which i give in input.
I mean when i select car name in next field it shows car price of selected car.

controller:

```
def index
@cars=Car.all
end
```

form:

```
 <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :carname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :carname  , :class => "form-control"%>
  </div>

 <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :fare %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :fare  , :class => "form-control"%>
  </div>
```

i tried javascript .but i don't know how to use rails object from javascript
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `@cars` instance variable value to a javascript variable using the `erb` tags. In your view, you could do something like.

```
<script>
 var cars_json = <%= raw @cars.to_json %>
</script>
```

After this the variable `cars_json` will have the JSON for all the cars and you can iterate through it whenever user enters in the HTML field.

I will suggest you to watch the below Railscast which talks about this.

- [#324 Passing Data to Javscript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)

Comment: @sriharisairamVentrapragada Glad it worked. please consider accepting the answer if it worked!

Comment: ya..i put it..votes with 15 reputation cannot showed public